# Generating dynamic column values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I want to dynamically create columns from one of the columns present in my data. In my case below i need to group my data by run_date and have each of the marketplace_code as a column name.

So basically I need to transform this data :

```
run_date,  marketplace_code,    count
06-APR-16,  US,                 1125197     
06-APR-16,  MX,                 26873   
06-APR-16,  IT,                 5197        
06-APR-16,  UK,                 23873   
05-APR-16,  US,                 486889
05-APR-16,  MX,                 486819
05-APR-16,  IT,                 536889
05-APR-16,  UK,                 986819
```

into something that looks like this :

```
run_date,   US,         MX,     IT,     UK
06-APR-16,  1125197,    26873,  5197,   23873
05-APR-16,  486889,     486819, 536889, 986819
```

I tried using pivot but I am not sure how to solve this one. Also we need to consider that the number of marketplace_code is not fixed and may increase. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google:  "Oracle dynamic pivot"

Answer (score 0):

**SQL for static pivot values**:

```
SELECT run_date,
       MAX( CASE marketplace_code WHEN 'US' THEN "count" END ) AS US,
       MAX( CASE marketplace_code WHEN 'MX' THEN "count" END ) AS MX,
       MAX( CASE marketplace_code WHEN 'IT' THEN "count" END ) AS IT,
       MAX( CASE marketplace_code WHEN 'UK' THEN "count" END ) AS UK
FROM   you_table
GROUP BY run_date;
```

**PL/SQL for dynamic pivot values**:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  TYPE string_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
  t_codes    string_table;
  p_sql      CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT marketplace_code
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_services, t_counts
  FROM   your_table;

  p_sql := EMPTY_CLOB() || 'SELECT run_date';
  FOR i IN 2 .. t_codes.COUNT LOOP
    p_sql := p_sql || ', MAX( CASE marketplace_code WHEN '''
                   || t_codes(i)
                   || ''' THEN "count" END ) AS "'
                   || t_codes(i)
                   || '"';
  END LOOP;
  p_sql := p_sql || ' FROM your_table GROUP BY run_date';

  OPEN :cur FOR p_sql;
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```